# golang excelize: how to set edit ranges in protect sheet

Tags: go, excelize

excelize version: 2.6.1

Here is the sample on excelize official document :

```
err := f.ProtectSheet("Sheet1", &excelize.FormatSheetProtection{  
Password: "password",  
EditScenarios: false,
.....
})
```

But I didn't find the way to set certain edit area like A1:B10  in a protect sheet.

How to set certain edit area?